# Eclipse project exporting to another pc

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I have project with swing windowbuilder packages on eclipse Mars 4.5.1 in one PC. When I tried copy project folder to another pc I couldn't open design mode for my classes. How can I export my project for using same dev environment on both PC's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually copying and pasting a project's folder try the "Export" option under File menu.

You need to choose the "export destination" i.e. the packaging type of your export say a JAR file. Copy this jar file on your destination machine.

Then, you just need to import this JAR on the destination machine.